# Embed unique custom form in all rows of a view

Tags: views, 8, forms, ajax

I want to create a custom form that will be embedded on each row for visitor to submit an email for that specific row.

I suppose I have to create a custom form (which I have done before) but **how do I embed it on each row** ?  `hook_views_data_alter(array &$data)` is the right way ?

Other questions (but not that important) are how do I make it unique (know which row the user has submitted) ? Another requirement is to be submitted without reload of whole page (ajaxy form).

Comment: I would try and create a variable that contains the form using `THEME_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$variables) {` and then print out the custom variable on views-view-fields--[view-name].html.twig

Comment: If you want to avoid the template system all together. You can override a field value in [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/comment/62573#comment-62573)

Answer (score 2):

That's a lot questions in one post. Two things may help you:

First, if you have more than one instance of a form on one page, you need different formIds. So implement the getFormId with a variable, like so:

```
public function getFormId() {
    return "mysuper_form-".$this->whatEverCounter;
}
```

Then, you will need to create your form yourself with the constructor (cause you need your state to be set from outside) and pass that instance to the formBuilder, for example like so

```
$idForm = new myForm($whatEverCounter);
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($idForm);
```

Second, for the "each row" topic:
If you really have one form per row, you will have one submit per row also - no problem. Or, you have one form with one element per row. Then just enumerate your elements like so:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    foreach ($ems as $e) {
       $form['toggle'.$e] = []
    ]
```

If you need an ajax submit callback, use the '#ajax' attribute, like so:

```
'#ajax' => array(
        // Function to call when event on form element triggered.
        'callback' => [$this, 'toggleButtonPress'],
        // Effect when replacing content. Options: 'none' (default), 'slide', 'fade'.
        'effect' => 'fade',
        // Javascript event to trigger Ajax. 
        'event' => 'click',
        'progress' => array(
        // Graphic shown to indicate ajax. Options: 'throbber' (default), 'bar'.
        'type' => 'throbber',
        // Message to show along progress graphic. Default: 'Please wait...'.
        'message' => NULL,
        ),
```

Comment: How do I embed a custom form to a view is the MAIN question, reformatted the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @GiorgosK while this doesn't answer the "main" question, you will still need to do all the above :)

Comment: @NoSssweat thanks I know and in my question I sort of hint that this is the part that I know.  The most pressing question is how to embed the form to views